# System tray text instead of icon

Tags: java, swing, awt

How can I display text in the system tray instead of an icon?
I want to display a percentage for example.

```
final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(createImage("image.png", "tray icon"));
```

The code above is to set an icon, but how can I set text such as `100%` to display in the system tray? This is specifically on OSX.

Comment: TrayIcon is not SWT, so is this anything to do with SWT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can draw the text onto an image, this does the job although you are still using an image. I don't think there is an other way to do it.

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
g2d.drawString("100%", x, y);
g2d.dispose();
trayIcon.setImage(image);
```

Comment: drawString requires two arguments though? its asking for either ("",float,float) or ("",int,int)

Comment: @ThatGuy343 yeah the position, forgot to add that.

Comment: Is there any way around the 16x16 width limit? 100% does not fit and is cut off.

Comment: @ThatGuy343 You could change the font size, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249592/how-to-change-font-size-in-drawstring-java

Comment: horizontally the icon could exceed 16.